# Trouble calculating small small numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, freeze

I have some trouble with my code. I'm trying to calculate the time it takes for two objects in space to collide due to their gravitational pull. I made the code work in python, but can't get it to work in c++. I've discovered that c++ interprets a small value as 0, and thereby no change happens, and the program freezes.

The code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    double gamma = 166857 / 2500000000000000, r = 1.5, width = 0.3;
    float a1 = 0, a2 = 0, v1 = 0, v2 = 0, dt = 0.1, elapsedTime;
    int m1 = 90, m2 = 90;
    
    double acceleration(int m) {
        return ((gamma * m) / (r * r));
    }
    
    double speed(double a, double v) {
        return (a * dt + v);
    }
    
    double distance(double a, double v) {
        return (a * dt * dt + v * dt);
    }
    int main()
    {
    
        while (r > 2 * width) {
            // Represents person 1's acceleration
            a1 = acceleration(m2);
            //Represents person 2's acceleration
            a2 = acceleration(m1);
    
            // Calculates the speeds
            v1 = speed(a1, v1);
            v2 = speed(a2, v2);
    
            // Changes distance between the two objects
            r -= distance(a1, v1) + distance(a2, v2);
    
            // Saves the time it takes for the objects to collide
            elapsedTime += dt;
        }
        std::cout << elapsedTime;
   }
```

If anyone knows why this happens, and has a solution; please let me know. That would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `166857 / 2500000000000000` will do integer division; `166857.0 / 2500000000000000` will make it do floating point (double) division.

Comment: Besides, if you need a high precision, try to use `double` instead of `float`

Comment: Also worth noting that doubles are formatted with only 6 d.p. by default, when you're printing out values and comparing them with Python.

Comment: You also have `long double` so you could make it `long double gamma = 166857.L / 2500000000000000.L;`

Comment: Ah, yeah of course. Thanks, @Richard Critten!

Comment: Note: `(a * dt + v) * dt` is more numerically stable than `a * dt * dt + v * dt`.